# Command Line & and &&

Tags: windows, file-io, command-line, batch-file

so currently what I am attempting to do is, remote onto a different server, launch a scheduled task, exit, change to a specified folder on my desktop, write a file

My code currently looks as such

```
C:MyOriginalFolder> psexec \\MYREMOTESERVER -u MYUSERNAME cmd
C:MYREMOTESERVER> SCHTASK.......
C:MYREMOTESERVER> exit & cd C:\\Users\ce132d & echo "Logged off" > MyLog.txt
//expected: the folder C:\\Users\ce132d should have a text file called MyLog.txt

//what happens:  I end up in C:MyOriginalFolder with no MyLog.txt file created
```

When I remove the &'s and test it command by command, all is dandy and the expected behavior happens. But when linking them together with & and &&, the expected behavior does not happen.

So my question is this: is there some way of one-lining the actions of exiting, changing directory, and writing a text file?
I am eventually going to check if loging into the remote server was successful or not, and want to put those 3 actions into a if (successful login) {do 3 tasks} else {write error log}..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send your remote server `exit & cd C:\\Users\ce132d & echo "Logged off" > MyLog.txt`.
Why do you expect that the `cd ...` should have any effect on your local directory?

When you send the commands line by line then your `exit` will *EXIT* the remote server context, then you are again on your local machine, therefore the rest of the commands works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `> MyLog.txt` is being evaluated before any of the commands are run, including the `cd`.  You can use `> C:\Users\ce132d\MyLog.txt` instead.

You can also use `>>` instead of `>` to append to a file.

Comment: This might be an issue later on, but when I input >exit & cd C:\\Users\ce132d when on the command prompt on the remote server, it does not move me to the correct directory